# How to get index in an array from random rotation degrees?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm still working on my spinning wheel. For now I wanna show people the results on screen by Text("(Array[index])"). the question is i know the random rotation degrees but i don't know how to transfer it to that "result angles" index :P ,Any help I will appreciate it !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMmc5.png)

I use Path to draw the wheel:

```
var slices: Array<OneChance.OneChanceData> {

    let sum = Double(newChoices.count)

    var endDeg: Double = 0.0

    var tempSlices: [OneChance.OneChanceData] = []

    for (color, text) in zip(colors, newChoices) {

        let degrees: Double = Double(360 / sum)

        

        tempSlices.append(OneChance.OneChanceData(startAngle: Angle(degrees: endDeg), endAngle: Angle(degrees: endDeg + degrees), text: text, color: color))

        endDeg += degrees

    }

    return tempSlices

}
```

The wheel view like:

```
ForEach(0..<chanceVM.newChoices.count) { i in

                    EachSliceView(chanceData: self.chanceVM.slices[i])

                }
```

I use onTapGesture to get random wheel spinning degrees:

```
.onTapGesture {

                        self.chanceVM.showResult = false

                        self.chanceVM.rotateDegree = 0.0

                        playSound(sound: "wheelSpinning13s", type: "mp3")

                        self.chanceVM.allowToTapAgain = false

                        withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 13.0)) {

                            self.chanceVM.rotateDegree = Double.random(in: 5400.0...7200.0)

                        }

                        print("\(chanceVM.rotateDegree)")

                        print("\((Int(chanceVM.rotateDegree) % 360))")

                        print("\((Int(chanceVM.rotateDegree) % 360)/(360/chanceVM.newChoices.count))")

                        self.chanceVM.delayText()

                        self.chanceVM.delayTap()

                    }
```

So how can i get the index after random spinning degrees?

Comment: Is this a programming problem or a math problem, I am not sure what exactly you are asking about

Comment: I'm not sure, For example i get random rotations degrees: 5870.74773  and the pointer point the answer from in the newChoices Array, how to connect them together?

Comment: So you have you `slices` array. You have the random angle. You can iterate over theses slices to find the corresponding one which include that angle. `let slice = slices.first(where: { $0.startAngle <= randomAngle && $0.endAngle < randomAngle }; let textToDisplay = slice.text`, or something like that, no?

Comment: Something like `let slice = (7200-5400) / array.count` and then `let index = (rotate - 5400) / slice`

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your help i think i figured it out, i use : Text(chanceVM.newChoices[chanceVM.newChoices.count - (Int(chanceVM.rotateDegree) % 360)/(360/chanceVM.newChoices.count) - 1]) I don't know why i just use mius 1 then i get the result.

Comment: Thank you ,I will try your method later. @Larme

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think my solutions are similar like yours, but at last step  I have to mius 1 to get the correct choice from array.

Comment: It gave me the correct result without subtracting one, I used Int instead of double to get an integer division so maybe that is the difference